# How to get image url from matrix field

Tags: templating, assets

I have an image in a matrix-field, but can't get the url from it.
`dump(block.image.one().url)` says `NULL`. My code is:

```
{% if entry.hero %}
  {% for block in entry.hero %}
    {% if block.type == 'hero' %}
      {% set heroImage = block.image.one() %}
      <div class="cell hero center padding-1" style="background-image: url({{ heroImage.url }});">
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

`image.one()` or `image.first()`, as well as `.url` or `.getUrl()` doesn't work the same.

What works though is `{{ block.image.one().folderPath }}{{ block.image.one().filename }}`

Does anyone know why? I'm on Craft CMS 3.3.15

Comment: Does the volume where your asset is have public urls enabled?

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The asset volume needs to have public urls enabled. Thanks seb.